# Want to keep only the very first observation of a variable by patient

Tags: sas, macros

[Example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viut9.png)

I am trying to retain only the first time a patient is diagnosed with a different growth condition based on a diagnosis date. So for instance if a patient's first time being diagnosed is on 04/2024, but they have this diagnosis flagged on other dates, I only want to keep the first time it happened. I also want the subsequent events to be flagged as 0 or ".". I tired using an array, but It was not working as intended. Using SAS.

However when I went to make sure the person wasn't being flagged on different days for the same variable, they were.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to process this in wide form, or transpose it to long format and use just BY-processing with `first.`. Example of the former:

```
proc sort data=have; by patientid diag_date; run;

data want;
   set have;
   by patientid diag_date;
   array arr_growth [*] growth_:;
   array arr_flags  [9] _TEMPORARY_; /* Implicitly retained. */
   
   if first.patientid then do i = 1 to dim(arr_growth);
      arr_flags[i] = 1;
   end;
   
   do i = 1 to dim(arr_growth);
      if arr_flags[i] then do;
         if arr_growth[i] eq 1 then arr_flags[i] = 0;
      end;
      else arr_growth[i] = 0; /* Or set to '.' */
   end;
   drop i;
run;
```